# How to: get new line between two spans?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I've been working on implementing Parsley.js into a Rails app that is using Bootstrap for CSS and JS classes. I have everything working, except some CSS that is giving me a headache. For some reason, if there are any validation error the addon's height gets resized to occupy the whole space. I tried using the max-height property without any luck, and I think is something that can be fixed with a clearfix. Can someone please help me? An example of my error can be found here: http://plnkr.co/edit/6i6yqSvNXQLCDNvvK5el?p=preview . Thanks is advanced.

Edit: Here is a mockup of my desired output:
[image]

Comment: hi...when the error shows up..what i need to do..??

Comment: can u be more precise of what u need?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I just don't want the addon to change its height. It should stay the same as before the error, and the error itself should be on a new line. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have try to solve this with js but unfortunately not getting the js so I have added `position: absolute` to the error messages.

I have added following styles

```
#new_user{
  position:relative;
}
.help-block{
  position:absolute;
}
.has-error{
  margin-bottom:32px;
}
```

here is the updated code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/YzsdnGEPZmkMOLm7G1TS?p=preview

hope this will hep you.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! You should edit your post as the top and left are not necessary. Have a good day Sonasish, I appreciate your help!